# XAMPP and safe working environment

Tags: php, xampp, wamp, development-environment, web-development-server

Welcome,

I've got a quick question about PHP development environment. To be specific, I would like to use a program (maybe XAMPP or WAMP) for home use, php development. I am mostly worried about the security aspect of these two programs or programs suggested. Would they be safe for home use while hooked up to the internet? Are there any security measures that can be used to disable remote access, so that only my pc were able to access and control? Additionally, what program would you guys suggest using for PHP development (mysql, apache).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would they be safe for home use while hooked up to the internet? Are
>   there any security measures that can be used to disable remote access,
>   so that only my pc were able to access and control?

If you don't forward any ports and make sure to use a firewall on the computer (Windows Firewall should be enough in your case) in order to block all unwanted traffic coming to your PC, that shouldn't be too much of an issue.

> Additionally, what program would you guys suggest using for PHP
>   development (mysql, apache).

This is too broad of a question, generally just use whatever you're comfortable with. If you don't know what you would be most comfortable with, just start using the default configuration. For instance, XAMPP uses MariaDB and Apache.